# Como puedo hacer para que encuentre los elementos que quiero en el array que me dan, y los guardo en un nuevo array?

Tags: javascript, array

//Dado un array que contiene algunos meses del año desordenados, recorrer el array buscando los meses de
// "Enero", "Marzo" y "Noviembre", guardarlo en nuevo array y retornarlo.
//Si alguno de los meses no está, devolver: "No se encontraron los meses pedidos"
// Tu código:

function mesesDelAño(array) {

var array1 = [];

for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
if( array[i] == "Enero" && array[i] == "Marzo" && array[i] == "Noviembre"){

```
  array1 = ("Enero", "Marzo", "Noviembre");
  return array1;
}
else {
  return "No se encontraron los meses pedidos";
}
```

}
}

Comment: Los meses  "Enero", "Marzo" y "Noviembre" son fijos o ¿te pueden pedir alguna otra lista diferente?

Comment: Me proporcionas distintas listas, yo tengo que recorrer los array y encontrar esos tres meses, si están los tres meses retornar un nuevo array con los 3 meses, y si falta alguno de los 3, retornar que no se encontraron los elementos pedidos

Comment: Dado un array que contiene algunos meses del año desordenados, recorrer el array buscando los meses de // "Enero", "Marzo" y "Noviembre", guardarlo en nuevo array y retornarlo. //Si alguno de los meses no está, devolver: "No se encontraron los meses pedidos"

Comment: Editá tu pregunta y dale formato a tu código con el botón que indica `{}`, o seguí [esta ayuda](/editing-help#code). El código que proporcionás: ¿lo hiciste vos o te lo dieron como guía?

Comment: Por eso, los tres meses "Enero", "Marzo" y "Noviembre" son fijos y lo que cambia ¿son los meses desordenados? O también ¿es posible proporcionar tres meses diferentes para buscar?

Comment: A la pregunta le faltan datos... además que está mal formateada... Hablas que te dan 2 listas... y en el ejemplo tienes valores fijos... actualiza tu pregunta con lo que estás preguntando

Comment: //Dado un array que contiene algunos meses del año desordenados, recorrer el array buscando los meses de // "Enero", "Marzo" y "Noviembre", guardarlo en nuevo array y retornarlo. //Si alguno de los meses no está, devolver: "No se encontraron los meses pedidos" // Tu código:

function mesesDelAño(array) { }

Comment: Asi se me plantea el ejercicio, tengo que escribir el código para resolverlo dentro de esa function.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer lago así:

Le pasas a la función dos arreglos:

- datos: contiene los nombres de algunos meses del año desordenados.
- mesesBuscar: son los meses que tiene que buscar en en arreglo datos. En principio serían "Enero", "Marzo" y "Noviembre".

En la función mesesHallados contendrá los meses que encontró en el arreglo datos, si la cantidad de elementos coincide con la del arreglo mesesBuscar significa que encontró todos los meses, y retornará el arreglo mesesHallados, caso contrario retornará la cadena indicando que no se encontraron todos los meses pedidos.

```js
function buscarMesesDelAnio(datos, mesesBuscar) {
  let mesesHallados = datos.filter(function(mes) {
    if(mesesBuscar.indexOf(mes) >= 0) {
      return true;
    }
      
    return false;
  });
    
  if(mesesHallados.length == mesesBuscar.length) {
    return mesesHallados;
  } else {
    return "No se encontraron todos los meses pedidos.";
  }
}

let meses = ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Noviembre", "Junio", "Diciembre"];
let mesesBuscar = ["Enero", "Marzo", "Noviembre"];

let res = buscarMesesDelAnio(meses, mesesBuscar);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo intentaria manejar  con estados... primero buscaria las coincidencias y luego verificaria si todas las condiciones han sido cumplidas.

```
function mesesDelAño(array) {
  
  const nuevoArray=['Marzo','Noviembre','Enero']
  let findEnero
  let findMarzo
  let findNoviembre
  array.includes('Enero')?findEnero=true:findEnero=false
  array.includes('Marzo')?findMarzo=true:findMarzo=false
  array.includes('Noviembre')?findNoviembre=true:findNoviembre=false;
  return findEnero===true&&findMarzo===true&&findNoviembre===true?nuevoArray:"No se encontraron los meses pedidos"
}
```